# Twilio Web RTC Go restrictions on disconnected participants

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

**Prerequisites**

I have a web application with 1:1 video call participants. Node.js on backend.
Every participant can enter in and out of a meeting room infinite amount of times. Every time a same user connects to the room, new token is created and new identity attached to this access token respectively. So, after visit is finished, video insights show me statistics for WebRTC go room:

- Max Allowed: 2
- Count: 7
- Max Concurrent: 2

WebRTC Go rooms have restriction to have max 2 participants.
In fact, there are maximum two concurrent participants in a meeting room, but same user can leave-enter multiple times.

**Questions**

1. What field does WebRTC treats as max participants: `max concurrent` or `count`?
2. If it's the `count`, do you have any ideas/suggestions how can I bypass this restriction and consider a user which enters/leaves a meeting room as the same one, without creating new identity?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Go room, the maximum number of participants that you can have at the same time is 2 (max allowed).

`Max concurrent` is the maximum number of participants that were connected to a room at the same time, if you had a room where only one participant joined, Max concurrent would be 1.

`Count` is the number of connections that you had during the meeting. For example, if you had a meeting with 2 participants, and one of them leaves the room, and joins again, count will be 3 (2 for the participant that connected 2 times) and 1 for the participant that didn’t leave.

After a participant leaves, if he/she wants to join again, it is possible to use the same identity, but you need to be sure that the participant disconnected to avoid the error 53205
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/53205

Here you have some useful information
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/reconnection-states-and-events